# Angular set value not working after upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript, forms

after upgrading to the latest version of angular(11) and typescript 4, the setting of a nested value of a form stopped working, anyone out there that can help me with this?

The line that was working before and not working now is:
control.at(+z).get('unitTotalPrice').setValue(totalUnitPriceFormatted, {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});

below some of the edited code that should show everything that needs to be show

```
ngOnInit() 
  {
    .......
    this.myFormValueChanges$ = this.myorderForm.controls['itemRows'].valueChanges;
    this.myFormValueChanges$.subscribe(itemRows => this.updateTotalUnitPrice(itemRows));
        
        
        this.myorderForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          userName: [this.CurrentUserName],
          .....
          itemRows: this.formBuilder.array([this.initItemRows()]),
    
        })
        
        initItemRows() {
        const numberPatern = '^[0-9.,]+$';
        return this.formBuilder.group({
          sub_orderNumber : [''],
          .......
          unitTotalPrice: [''],
          ......
        },);
        .....
       }
       }
       
       updateTotalUnitPrice(itemRows: any) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.myorderForm.controls['itemRows'];
        ......
        for (let z in itemRows) {
          let totalUnitPriceFormatted = this.currencyPipe.transform(totalUnitPrice, 'GBP', '','1.2-2');
          control.at(+z).get('unitTotalPrice').setValue(totalUnitPriceFormatted, {onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false});
          console.log("what is totalUnitPriceFormatted here", totalUnitPriceFormatted)
          .......
          this.checkvalues();
        }
      }
      
      checkvalues(){
        let arr = <FormArray>this.myorderForm.controls.itemRows;
        console.log("what is arr here THIS IS THE WHOLE LINE", arr.value)
      }


the console.log in chrome says...
what is totalUnitPriceFormatted here xxx where xxx is the correct value

and
what is arr here THIS IS THE WHOLE LINE 
modified_date: "2021-04-06 16:22:08"
.......
unitTotalPrice: "0.00"
........

where uniTotalPrice contains the wrong information (0.00)

Please notice the checkvalues function is there just to check all the values of the array.
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I had to change the value of onlySelf from true to false, I willprobably never know why...but there you go...
let totalUnitPriceFormatted = this.currencyPipe.transform(totalUnitPrice, 'GBP', '','1.2-2');
control.at(+z).get('unitTotalPrice').setValue(totalUnitPriceFormatted, {onlySelf: false, emitEvent: false});